# pthread_self returns a large integer or 0, depending on whether libpthread is present or not

Tags: linux, pthreads, glibc

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
 int main(){
     std::cout<<pthread_self()<<std::endl;
}
```

When compiled with the command `g++ 1.cpp -o 1` and executed, the programs output is `0`, if compiled with the command `g++ 1.cpp -o 1 -lpthread` the output is a large number like 140062699310912.

I don't understand why.

```
# g++ 1.cpp -o 1 && ./1
0
# g++ 1.cpp -o 1 -lpthread && ./1
140268785461056
```

Comment: @ŁukaszŚlusarczyk I think the "output" is not the compilers return code, but rather the output of running the actual compiled program.

Comment: Please copy paste the command lines and output from the terminal window, showing the compilation and you running the command and the output from the runs.

Comment: To the OP: Please copy-paste a command-line session of building *and running* the program, in both variants. To clarify what you mean.

Comment: FWIW, on my g++, this produces a "large number" in *both* cases.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude :D guess it would be clear now.

Answer (score 4):

The POSIX standard does not specify the actual type that `pthread_t` corresponds to. In glibc, it is `unsigned long int`, which is why C++ streams can print its value. (This is not portable.)

Why does `pthread_self` return zero, but only when *not* linking with `-lpthread`?

Historically, glibc supported two different thread library implementations, LinuxThreads and NPTL. Some of the core `libpthread` functions have stubs within glibc itself that forward to the actual implementation if any is loaded, or perform some dummy fallback operation if no thread library is present in the process. For example, the dummy implementation of `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock` do nothing.

In the case of `pthread_self`, the dummy implementation has to return *some* value, and this value is zero. (POSIX does not reserve any `pthread_t` values to indicate failures or other corner cases, so this is fine.) When linking with `-lpthread`, the non-dummy implementation is used, which returns a pointer to the internal thread data structure (converted to `unsigned long`), and this value is never zero, not even for the initial (main) thread. This is why the presence of `-lpthread` on the linker command line matters.

Others could not reproduce this behavior because they were either using non-glibc systems, or more recent versions of glibc. Nowadays, there is only one threading library implementation for glibc, the one that started out as NPTL, and it is tightly integrated with the rest of glibc. This means the forwarders are not necessary anymore, and in glibc 2.27, [`pthread_self` never returns zero](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22635). Incidentally, this change helps with implementing `std::thread`, where the value zero returned by `get_id()`: `std::thread::id{}` means that there is no ID, not that the thread is the main thread (as in older glibc versions without `libpthread` loaded). `libstdc++` therefore needs a kludge to support glibc 2.26 and older.

The forwarders had another benefit: They enable performance optimizations, and not just for `pthread_mutex_lock` (by doing nothing if `libpthread` is not linked in). Some `libpthread` functionality is available without `-lpthread`. This means that applications can use synchronization *and* they can check for the presence of symbols such as `pthread_create` or `pthread_cancel` (using a weak symbol reference). If these weak symbols are undefined, it is clear that the process must be single-threaded, as `libpthread` is absent, which means that no threads can be created. In this case, it is not necessary to use atomic instructions for reference counting, for example. (`std::shared_ptr` in `libstdc++` uses such an optimization.) But this optimization is increasingly ineffective because most process images contain `libpthread` these days: some library requires it, so it is loaded as an indirect dependency. This means that the forwarders have lost this other purpose as well, and they are gradually being removed from glibc. (glibc 2.32 added [`__libc_single_threaded`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Single_002dThreaded.html) to enable the single-threaded optimization even if `libpthread` is loaded, but no threads have been created.)